# knockout binding context pass parent as parameter

Tags: ajax, json, knockout.js

when i click my table row , i get info object passed to function $root.goToEvent. But i want to pass the upper level of that object , in this case **events[[1]]** together with **info** and **rules**. Screens and code are attached. thanks in advance.

HTML

```
  <table class="mainTable" style="width:820px" border="1" data-bind="with: dataToShow">
                <tr>
                    <td width="200px" valign="top">
                        <!-- Events List -->
                        <table class="events" >
                        <thead><tr><th >События</th></tr></thead>
                        <tbody id="eventsTable" data-bind="foreach: events">

                            <!-- ko with: info -->
                            <tr id="trEvent" data-bind="css: { selected : $data==$root.chosenEvent()}, click: $root.goToEvent">
                            <td data-bind="text: event_title"></td>
                            </tr>     
                            <!-- /ko-->
                        </tbody>
                        </table>
```

OBJECT:
https://flic.kr/p/nvsrQB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option it to `bind` your function with the appropriate context (`this`) and initial argument.

Something like:

```
data-bind="click: $root.goToEvent.bind($root, $parent)"
```

This would call `goToEvent` with the value of `this` set to `$root` and the first argument being the parent context (an `event` object in your code).

Comment: thanks, as i understand $parents[1] will pass the upper object, and $parents[2] upper than the last and so on  till the $root, right?

Comment: @DmitriiG. - yes- `$parents[0]` would be same as `$parent`, then from there you could move up the scopes. This page is the docs: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html